# The query string seems to affect page loading speed

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I'm working on [this](https://dickbutt-etaoin.c9.io).
It's hosted on c9.io, a [browser based collaborative programming IDE](https://c9.io/)

I have an index.php with a small script:

```
<?php
    $path = ltrim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/');
    $elements = explode('/', $path);
    if(is_numeric($elements[0])){
        require_once 'post.php';
    }elseif($elements[0]==''){
        require_once 'main.php';
    }else{
        require_once '404.php';
    }
?>
```

When there is nothing in the url (only https://dickbutt-etaoin.c9.io ) it displays the page pretty much instantly but keeps loading for another five seconds during which none of the javascript on the page works

When I have a few numbers (for instance https://dickbutt-etaoin.c9.io/241 ) it's about as fast as it gets.

**How can I make both the pages load at a normal speed?**

I've tried reversing the order of if statements and it doesn't change a thing. Both the pages are relatively big, contain both php and javascript and a giant css file.

Comment: Use chrome dev tools to analyze requests and responses in network tab.

Comment: Also there are javascript errors.

Comment: I did, [this](http://imgur.com/0Q5Qssh)  is what I got, it says it's downloading resources, but everything is already fully loaded. Also if I manually start main.php it's fast again.

Comment: Pretty sure it's just the browser showing the loading thing. That might mean some JavaScript is still running.

Comment: would ajax do that?

@Tyr where?

Comment: @Tyr I fixed the js errors, didn't help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some prodding in the network tab and googling, I found my answer.

I added this line of code to index.php

```
header('Connection: close');
```

Now it does what I wanted it to do. Thank you all for trying to help!